# How to check duplicate words in a string in C?

Tags: c, string

I am solving a problem in C where i have to find duplicate words in astring like

```
 char a[]="This is it This";
```

In above string "This" appears two times so I would like to count it as one.

Can anybody suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: Is this homework?  Look at strtok (for breaking up the string) and strcmp to check each token, from strtok, for the existence of your duplicate.  You can also move through the string one byte at a time looking for a search string using strcmp and pointer manipulation.  There are many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: not homework exactly.. @Jmquigley and i have to do it without using standard string function

Comment: What do you mean by "count as one"?  You want the second one removed? A pointer to the second occurrence?  Need a little more info.

Comment: whts i looking is to count number of words in string and in above comes out to be 4 but one word is comes twice here so i want to count it as one not two and hence total number of words would be 3 instead of 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a program that does what you're asking.  It is hard coded for 4 words of a max 99 characters.  That can be changed easily; I just fit it around your input.  I also used `strcmp` and `strcpy`.  Both of these functions can be implemented on your own (call them mystrcpy and mystrcmp and embed them).  I'm not rewriting the string functions for you.  I did show how to avoid strtok based on the other answer.  I looked them up and they are not complex, but they did not add anything to the program and I didn't want to reinvent the wheel.  Last of all, I just used a simple linear search in the `notInArray` function.  For a large data set this is not efficient (you would probably use some type of tree or hash).

This was compiled under gcc version 4.3.4

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int notInArray(char arr[][100], char *word, int size);

int main() {
  char a[] = "This is a This";
  char *ptr;
  char strarr[4][100];
  char word[100];
  int pos = 0;
  int count = 0;
  int i;

  memset(&strarr,0,sizeof(strarr));
  printf("%s\n\n",a);

  ptr = a;
  while (*ptr) {

    sscanf(ptr, "%s ", word);
    if (notInArray(strarr,word,4)) {
      strcpy(strarr[pos++],word);
      printf("%s\n", word);
    }

    while (!isspace(*ptr++) && *ptr) {}
  }

  for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    if (*strarr[i]) {
      printf("strarr[%d]=%s\n",i, strarr[i]);
      count++;
    }
  }

  printf("\nUnique wordcount = %d\n", count);

  return(0);
}

int notInArray(char arr[][100], char *word, int size) {
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if (*arr[i] && !strcmp(arr[i],word)) {
      return(0);
    }
  }

  return(1);
}
```

The output looks like:

```
~>a
This is a This

This
is
a
strarr[0]=This
strarr[1]=is
strarr[2]=a

Unique wordcount = 3
```

Enjoy.

Comment: thanks for your efforts ,would like to know how much it took to write above code??

Comment: This program was not that difficult to write.  I had to look up sscanf because I don't use it much and it's not the more "normal" way to write this type of parsing code.  The strtok function is usually a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably read words one at a time (e.g., using sscanf [Edit: just saw your comment -- it's still fairly easy without string functions -- just scan through to find space/non-space characters to find the words -- annoying but not major) and put them into an array (or, if you have a lot more than you've shown above, a binary search tree).

If you want a count of the number of times each word occurs, you can have an int (or whatever) in each node. If you just want to know the unique word in the input, you don't need a count, just a collection of words.